# Trying to get a cascading dropdownlist to work in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to change the items in a dropdownlist based on the value of a separate dropdownlist. I was told that a cascading dropdownlist was what I want. I followed a tutorial for asp.net mvc 4 and my code is below but it doesn't work and I can't see any problems with it.

Here is my jquery/ajax code that runs when a user changes a value for the parent dropdownlist:

```
$('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            var modelData = {
                paperType: $("#paperTypeJList").text,
                urgency: $("#urgencyJList").val(),
                numOfPages: $("#numOfPagesJList").val()
            };

            var typeValue = $("#paperTypeJList").val();
            var url = @Url.Action("UrgencyList", "Home", typeValue);

            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                var items = "<option>Select the Urgency</option>";
                $.each(data, function(i, urgency) {
                    items += "<option value='" + urgency.Value + "'>" + urgency.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#urgencyJList").html(items);
            });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getNewPrice","Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: modelData,
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    });
```

Here are the methods that populate the relevant dropdownlists:

```
public SelectList GetPaperTypeSelectList()
    {
        var paperTypes = PaperType.GetPaperTypes();

        return new SelectList(paperTypes.ToArray(), "deadlineFormat", "typeName");
    }

    public ActionResult PaperTypeList()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(GetPaperTypeSelectList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult UrgencyList(string deadlineValue)
    {
        var urgencyList = from u in Urgency.GetUrgency()
                          where u.deadlineFormat.Contains(deadlineValue) == true
                          select u;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(urgencyList.ToArray(), "urgencyValue", "urgencyName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

And last but not least, here is my jquery code that creates the items for the parent dropdownlist:

```
$(function () {
var url = '@Url.Action("PaperTypeList","Home")';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var items = "<option>Select the Type of Paper</option>";
    $.each(data, function (i, papertype) {
        items += "<option value='" + papertype.Value + "'>" + papertype.Text + "</option>";
    });
    $('#paperTypeJList').html(items);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the parameter name of the action UrgencyList to

```
public ActionResult UrgencyList(string id)
```

MVC cannot parse the name 'deadlineValue', you would have to map a new Route, but I do not recommend this.

To understand more about the routes, open the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file. There you will see that 'id' is mapped by default by MVC.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",//Id is mapped by default
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I changed the parameter name to id and I'm now getting a compilation error for the following lines:

Comment: var typeValue = $("#paperTypeJList").val();
var url = @Url.Action("UrgencyList", "Home", typeValue);

Comment: It is saying that typeValue does not exist in the current context